# C# WPF Window Not Shown Correctly After Restore

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I have a very generic WPF window that starts maximized. When this window is minimized to task bar, and then restored the window no longer fills the screen. It shows a small portion of the desktop on the right hand side. Windows still considers it as maximized and when set to normal and then maximized again it looks like it should until being minimized again.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
    }

    private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void MaxBtn_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        //Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        resizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        maximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    private void ResBtn_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        resizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        maximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    private void MinBtn_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
    private void TitleBar_DblClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal){ this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; return; }
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) { this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal; return; }
    }
}
```

Your thoughts?
UPDATE:

Seems to related to the can resize property. If I set it to ca minimize it is fine. resize with grip or can resize cause the window to change sizes after being minimized to task bar.

```
<Window x:Class="QuoteClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuoteClient"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
<Grid>
    <local:TitleBar VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDoubleClick="TitleBar_DblClick"/>
    <local:ExitBtn x:Name="exitBtn" Margin="0,2.5,2.5,0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="15" MouseLeftButtonUp="ExitBtn_Click"/>
    <local:MinBtn x:Name="minimizeBtn" Margin="0,2,37,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonUp="MinBtn_Click"/>
    <local:MaxBtn x:Name="maximizeBtn" Margin="0,2,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="13" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonUp="MaxBtn_Click"/>
    <local:ResBtn x:Name="resizeBtn" Margin="0,2,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Visibility="Hidden" MouseLeftButtonUp="ResBtn_Click"/>
    <DataGrid Margin="10,25,10,10" Background="Black" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF575656" RowBackground="#FF403C3C" Cursor="Cross"/>
    <Expander Header="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,-17,0,0" Width="100" FontSize="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="332" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Foreground="#FFFFFEFE">
        <Expander.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.9" ScaleX="0.9"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Expander.RenderTransform>
    </Expander>


</Grid>
```

UPDATE 2:
screenshot: https://ibb.co/iN2n7F
Screenshot of Answer: https://ibb.co/c3BHra

ANSWER: Issue is something with my display only. Haven't figured it out yet, but the program operates as expected on another PC. Many thanks to @Vanna who helped me parse that out.

Comment: I edited my post. The MaxBtn and ResBtn were leftovers from trying other things. setting the max height and width was a fix so the WPF window did not hide the task bar. Using your code, the window still hides the task bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
This code is tested working

**MainWindow.xml**

```
<Window x:Class="QuoteClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuoteClient"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseDoubleClick="Window_MouseDoubleClick">

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Button x:Name="ExitBtn" Content="Exit" Width="75" Click="ExitApplication" />
    <Button x:Name="MaximizeBtn" Content="max" Width="75" Click="MaximizeState"/>
    <Button x:Name="NormalBtn" Content="normal" Width="75" Click="NormalState" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button x:Name="MinimizeBtn" Content="min" Width="75" Click="MinimizeState"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
private static bool _isPrivStateMinimized;
private static int _left, _top;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
    MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
}

protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{            
    base.OnStateChanged(e);
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        _isPrivStateMinimized = true;
        return;
    }
    if (_isPrivStateMinimized)
    {
        if(WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            _left = Left;
            Left = 0;
            _top = Top;
            Top = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Left = _left;
            Top = _top;
        }
    }
    _isPrivStateMinimized = false;
    BringIntoView();
}

private void MaximizeState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    MaximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    NormalBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void NormalState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    NormalBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    MaximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void MinimizeState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}

private void ExitApplication(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        DragMove();
}

private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        NormalBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MaximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        return;
    }
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    MaximizeBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    NormalBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Window style is none. On first load it is Normal center screen, then can be maximize by either double click on titlebar or the button. Like i said earlier it is related to the resize mode. if set to `NoResize` or `CanMinimize` there is no issue. but i would like the window to be resizable

Comment: So it is still happening even with your code copied and pasted. I guess there is something wrong in my particular environment...

Comment: yes brand new solution. had to change namespace etc to match of course. no I do not want it to hide task bar. Ill put screen shot in original post

Comment: Added links to my post of both yours and mine.